# can MITM read my metamask seed phrase when I click "Reveal Secret Recovery Phrase" in the wallet?

Tags: wallet, security, mnemonic-seed, wallet-security

I worry someone is leaching my WiFi and potentially trying to do a MITM attack. If I click "Reveal Secret Recovery Phrase" in my metamask wallet extension, will they be able to read it via WiFi?
Or is it revealed just locally on my machine and no plain text is sent over the router?

I'm no computer expert so I'm not even sure if this question makes any sense.

I have a wifi extender paired with router via qss.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No a MITM won't be able to see it unless you transmit it in plaintext across the wire (e.g. into a personal web app using HTTP instead of HTTPS).

You should be more worried about man in the browser (e.g. malicious extension), or malware on your device. In this case an attacker could retrieve local data, see your clipboard, or take screenshots which may reveal your seed phrase.

An attacker might also switch out a transaction about to be signed with a malicious transaction (one they crafted), and when you sign it you end up signing their transaction (e.g. to empty your wallet).

This is unlikely - but possible. The more you download pirated software or go on malicious website the more likely you are to be infected with something that has access to your machine and can do the above.

Answer (score 0):

Your secret key is locally placed in your system it won't be send through your router